# Alternative to componentWillReceiveProps for my particular use case

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, lifecycle, react-component

Since `componentWillReceiveProps` will be deprecated, I have heard alternatives to use `componentDidUpdate`, but the problem is `componentDidUpdate` will also be invoked on state changes as well.
Now, most common answers to this question is to compare the previous and current props and do the required action.

But, I want to do certain actions whenever prop changes regardless of whether prop is same as the previous or not.

An example for such a use case would be like this.

**Use case 1:**
I have a search bar on the top of my page, when user types in the search bar and then the search button is clicked, all the other components have to do certain actions. So, when an a string is searched, I used to set a state in redux. And all the other components would get to know these changes from `componentWillReceiveProps`. Now I wouldn't check for if `prevProps` and `currentProps` were the same. Each time when `componentWillReceiveProps` is invoked, I'd do the certain actions, because, if the user removed the string searched, and retypes the same string, and clicks on the search button again, the other components still need to do those actions, even if the searched string is same as the previous one.  So comparing current and previous props is not something that I can do here.

Now with `componentDidUpdate`, if I do those actions without any check, since it also invoked on state changes, it wouldn't work.

**Use case 2:**
Listening to changes in routes, I use React Router which uses location objects. Now I would use `componentWillReceiveProps` in this case as well, to listen to the location changes and update my component accordingly, regardless of if the same location object is passed again. So, same issue as the previous use case

What would be the ideal way to approach such scenarios?

Comment: How about checking for the inverse. Check if state has changed and if it has don't run the functions that would be required if props changed? Or does the state also change with the props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps add an additional field to Redux Store which would convey information that a new action from user happened, such as **timestamp** of clicking the search button, or a **UUID**, and then compare in **componentDidUpdate** with that.

Comment: Technically this would work. But, I wanted to know if there is a different approach to such problems. This solution seems a bit hacky, even if it would work.
This use case seems very common and wanted to know what is the normal approach to this.

Comment: I agree. See if you can somehow avoid the need to compare props. What actions you speak about need to be done even on the same string?

Comment: By action ,for example, in the use case I have mentioned, is calling an api which fetches some result for that searched string. Now, take for example, stack overflow search itself. Each time when you press enter after searching, it'll fetch the latest results. It would do it regardless, if the same string is searched or not.
Ultimately what I want is there should be a way to know that the component will be receiving new props, but it shouldn't be coupled with the componentDidUpdate which would be invoked on both prop and state change. Am I making sense?

Comment: Maybe you should move such logic to the parent component which registers the click and then run it from there.